# How does the Neural Network model is developed using lead times in forecast?

Tags: time-series, neural-networks, predictive-models

In most Neural Network (NN) forecasting studies on Sea Surface Temperature, they stated that they create different models for different lead times of 3,6,9, or 12 months. I still can not understand how is this done. And I need explanation of what does it mean b lead times and exactly how do we use it in the NN model.